# python sampling from different distributions

Tags: python, statistics, sampling

I might have asked this previously, but the question might not be clear.
I am trying to create a sample distribution of the sample median by conducting 300 repeated random sampling by drawing a sample size of 50 from 3 different normal distributions:

```
subpop1: mean = 100, std dev = 40 (14 of the 50 sample from subpop1)
subpop2: mean = 200, std dev = 70 (20 of the 50 sample from subpop2)
subpop3: mean = 300, std dev = 80 (16 of the 50 sample from subpop3)
```

how then can I approach this problem? this is what I've done so far:

```
repeat = 300
samplesize_list = [14, 20, 16] ]
std_list = [40, 70, 80]
mean_list = [100, 200, 300]
repeat_median = np.empty(repeat, dtype = float)
for j in range(len(samplesize_list)):
    size = samplesize_list[j]
    for m in range(len(mean_list)):
        mean = mean_list[m]
        for z in range(len(std_list)):
            std = std_list[m]
            for i in range(repeat): 
                sample_data = np.random.normal(mean, std, size)
                repeat_median[i] = np.median(sample_data)
sns.distplot(repeat_median, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

im not sure where I've gone wrong, as am in an introductory course to python, I need help with my coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with plotting but as far as the math:

```
import random
import numpy as np

groups = [
    {'label': 'sub_one', 'mean': 100, 'std_dev': 40, 'size': 14},
    {'label': 'sub_two', 'mean': 200, 'std_dev': 70, 'size': 20},
    {'label': 'sub_three', 'mean': 300, 'std_dev': 80, 'size': 16} 
]

def median(mean, std_dev):
    data = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev)
    get_median = np.median(data)
    return get_median


group_all = []

for i in range(300):
    for i in range(groups[0]['size']):
        group_all.append(median(groups[0]['mean'], groups[0]['std_dev']))

    for i in range(groups[1]['size']):
        group_all.append(median(groups[1]['mean'], groups[1]['std_dev']))

    for i in range(groups[2]['size']):
        group_all.append(median(groups[2]['mean'], groups[2]['std_dev']))

print(len(group_all))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 median.py 
> 15000
> ```

Comment: first do you understand dictionaries?

Comment: In that line I'm running the function `median` and I'm passing values from the list `groups` , each group is a `dictionary` and the first one is `group[0]`, I use this to pass `group[0]['size']` etc, the function then returns a `value` that I'm appending to a new list called `group_one` after each run its appending one outcome, and we do that 300 times

Comment: if you are not familiar with dictionaries I could reproduce it without them

Comment: oh right I get it! I'm unsure about one point though! lets say I want to do 300 repeated random sampling of size 50 samples (containing 14 from group 1, 20 from group 2 and 16 from group 3)

Comment: so is there a way I could store the list of samples I can get from that?

Comment: say... I draw 14 medians randomly from group 1, 20 from group 2 and 16 from group 3, then repeat this 300 times and store all the medians in a single list

Comment: im also not sure how do I get python to recognise that the groups are normally distributed and that it should be random

Comment: look at the update, we set all the groups to the amount of iterations we want of each and to append to one list `group_all` and we do this entire process 300x, I printed `len(group_all)` to show it contains 15000 results, as for the normal distribution and randomness we handle that in the function `median` using `np.random.normal(mean, std_dev)`

Comment: oh thanks so much! I understand better now. do you mind explaining the def code u written?  I don't get the for loop underneath the def.

Comment: actually you know with the modification you decided to make modification we made it should we should remove the `for` loop

Comment: it serves no purpose since we are now handling the size individually outside of the function

Comment: Im going to update now see what Im saying instead of passing size into the function we can pass size into the iterations for each group

Comment: If this worked for you, accepting the answer would be greatly appreciated :)